# Android two Canvas within single Custom View (within onDraw())

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have custom View.

within this I  have onDraw() function.

```
  @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{

     canvas.drawLine(0,0,600,200,black);

    }
```

within this onDraw() I want to create one more canvas .  Suppose canvas1.

```
  @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{

     canvas.drawLine(0,0,600,200,black);

     canvas1.drawLine(0,0,500,100,Red);        
    }
```

And on The button Click I want to make the canvas1 plot visible and Invisible. but I     don't want  to redraw again.
First thing: **Is this possible to create one more canvas within onDraw()?** **And make it visible and InVisible.**

If you have any other way to do this please suggest me, but apart from  solution to redraw() again. I can't redraw() there is  some problem in my case.

Hope you have understood my problem? 
  please  suggest me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to design 2 custom view and put on top of each other and make background of bottom one transparent.

Answer (score 4):

for using another Canvas u need draw a bitmap on second canvas and then draw that on canvas

```
Bitmap bitmap ;
Canvas c2 = new Canvas(bitmap);

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{

     canvas.drawLine(0,0,600,200,black);

     // Draw on Second canvas
     c2.drawLine(0,0,500,100,Red); 
     // Draw second canvas (c2) to first one
     canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

}
```

Comment: How to make  it visible and Invisible?

Comment: use boolean as condition to draw/remove this layer

Comment: but in this condition to show it again , i need to redraw it again.